# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' - MySQLdb Python

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm, encode, mysql-python

I am writing a Python code with MySQL.

My DB schema is as follows:

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
|    |      |
|    |      |
```

Following is a part of my code:

```
cursor = self.conn.cursor()
query = ("SELECT name FROM TABLENAME WHERE id = '%s'", (str(id.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'utf-8'),)))
cursor.execute(query)
```

I am passing the ID from the URL.

And getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

I get the results when I hard-code the valud of ID in the query. But for some reason it is not working when I pass in a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query parameters should be passed as a second parameter to `execute()`:

```
cursor = self.conn.cursor() 
query = "SELECT name FROM TABLENAME WHERE id = %s"
cursor.execute(query, (str(id.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'utf-8')), ))
```

Note that you don't need the single quotes around the `%s` placeholder - the database driver would put them automatically if needed depending on the query parameter type.

Comment: Thanks for your help @alecxe .. The error got resolved.But now it says : 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @KreenaMehta what about just `cursor.execute(query, (id, ))`?