# Inserting python iteration of lists into mysql Database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract medium data and save it to the database. I am able to extract data into lists and clubbed them using zip function. But when I am inserting the data it is not getting inserted.

I have iterated to zip function to save data to a database. But not getting the required outcome. I have crawled medium posts successfully and there is nothing wrong with the sequence of my tables in the database.

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", 
       password="Jai@1998", database="crawldb")
cursor = mydb.cursor()


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.set_headless()
assert opts.headless
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)
browser.get('https://medium.com/')


comp = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "streamItem 
       streamItem-extremePostPreview js-streamItem"]')

authors = []
timeline = []

for i in range(len(comp)):
    x = comp[i].find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class = "postMetaInline 
        postMetaInline-authorLockup u-padding0 u-flexShrink1 u- 
        noWrapWithEllipsis"]')
    authors.append(x)
    y = comp[i].find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class = "ui-caption u- 
        noWrapWithEllipsis"] ')
    timeline.append(y)




 topics = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class = "ui-h2 ui-xs-h4 
          ui-clamp3"]')
 descriptions = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "ui- 
                summary ui-clamp2 u-marginTop2"]')


for title, desc, author, time in zip(topics, descriptions, authors, 
                                     timeline):
    print("topics : descriptions : authors : timeline")
    print(title.text + ": " + desc.text + ": "+ author.text + ": " + 
          time.text, '\n')


    sql = "INSERT INTO `DATAS`(topics, descriptions, authors, time) 
           VALUES(%s , %s , %s , %s)", (title.text, desc.text , 
           author.text , time.text)

    try:
        cursor.executemany(sql)
        mydb.commit()
        print("data inserted!!")

    except:
          mydb.rollback()

          mydb.close()                
          print("data not inserted!!")
```

The output is the extracting data and data not inserted! in SQL.

Comment: Did you try inserting fake data yourself and see if your sql working as intended?

Comment: Yeah! it is inserting data manually. no problem with that.

Comment: Remove the `try-except` block from the for-loop. You are hiding all excpetions/tracebacks that could help you troubleshoot the issue. Hint: you are using [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) incorrectly, in several ways.

Comment: replacing execute in place of executemany doesn't work too!

Comment: removing try/except block from for loop still doesn't work!!

Comment: Of course, just removing the exception handling doesn't make your code work. But it no longer hides the exception that raises when your code breaks, so you now have a concrete pointer to the issue in your code. Do you see an error being printed now? What does it say?

Comment: Well, it says : " errno=2055, values=(addr, 'Connection not available.'))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: Connection not available."  But I've checked(on Workbench 8.0) server is up and running.

Comment: Please add the complete traceback, starting from the line *Traceback (most recent call last):*, to your question via the edit dialog. Depending on how long the scraping activity takes, the connection you create might time out before you use it. Move the connection and cursor instantiation to where you are about to use them, e.g. before the for loop.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 392, in cmd_query
    query = query.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 405, in cmd_query
    errno=2055, values=(addr, 'Connection not available.'))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: Connection not available.

Comment: It is some sqlconnector tor issue

Comment: No, it's not. As I mentioned in my first comment, you are executing the query incorrectly. You pass a tuple as the only argument to `execute`; _not_ a query string _and_ a tuple of parameters. The connection object attempts to encode the query, an AttributeError raises because the tuple you pass as query doesn't have an `encode` method. The connection catches the AttributeError and raises the OperationalError. That's admittedly weird, but nevertheless the way its done. Fix the arguments you pass on your call to `execute`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' - MySQLdb Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352283/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-encode-mysqldb-python)

Comment: It raises another error: cursor.execute(sql , (str(title.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'utf-8')), ) , (str(desc.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'utf-8')), ) , (str(author.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'utf-8')), ) , (str(time.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'utf-8')), ))
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the gist of the answer in the duplicate Q&A. I get the impression that, unless someone posts working code to solve *your specific* problem, this will lead nowhere. You should really try to apply the *solution* given in an answer, not indiscriminately copy the code used to illustrate it in the context of another question.